# TypeError: int is not callable

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, max, typeerror

So I did my research but I still cant figure out why Im getting this error:

`TypeError: int is not callable`

Heres my code:

```
count = []
for row in Matrix:
     count.append(row[0][0].Value)

results = map(int, count)    

print max(results)
```

count list contained a list of string ints, I converted these to pure ints and then I wanted to find the max number but I get the error.

what am I not seeing here?

btw, `print min(count)` works fine....

Comment: Why are you calling max() on the count list and not on the results lists?

Comment: Maybe you did an assignment to `max`, try `print max` and see the output.

Comment: map(int, count) where count is a list of integer strings is clearly working.

Comment: Your example program [works flawlessly for me](http://ideone.com/y7K7jm). Please provide a **complete**, short example program that demonstrates the error. See http://SSCCE.ORG for more info.

Comment: @user2618501 - sorry that was a typo. fixed it.

Comment: @LeonYoung - this is very strange, when i print max alone, it gives me the highest value, but I have not set max to anything. What you see is the only script being used so im confused.

Comment: If `print(max)` prints *anything* other than `<built-in function max>`, that means you overwrote the name somehow. Are you doing this in the console, by any chance? As others have said, the code you posted does not demonstrate the problem.

Comment: print(max) does print something but not <built-in function max> so yes you are correct as are others. Ill get it to work now...thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're trying to use a number as a function somewhere.

Earlier in your program, did you do something like `map = 6` or `max = 6`? If so, you overrode either the `map` or `max` function(s), making them unusable.

To fix this, change the names of the variable names so they no longer overwrite the builtins.